# How to pass key and other required parameter with screen value so it can be used in navigator?

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation

I have a navigator, which has 4 options. I declared list of screens:

```
      List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
      return [
      const MainMenuScreen(),
      const LeveloneScreen(),
      const SettingsScreen(),
      const PlaySessionScreen(),
      const LevelSelectionScreen(),
      ];
      }
```

But for const PlaySessionScreen() const LevelSelectionScreen() I get error message saying: 1 positional argument expected by 'PlaySessionScreen.new', but 0 found. Try adding the missing argument.

On the screen itself I have 2 parameters that required to have:

```
    class PlaySessionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    final GameLevel level;

    const PlaySessionScreen(this.level, {super.key});

    @override
    State<PlaySessionScreen> createState() => _PlaySessionScreenState();
    }
```

I tried to include these 2 parameters on the existing screen with navigation along with final Game level, but it didn't work.

Here is how the navigation itself looks like:

```
                 currentPageIndex = index;
          if (currentPageIndex == 1) {
          Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PlaySessionScreen()),
          );
```

Comment: But in navigation you are not passing the value of game level in PlaySessionScreen()

Comment: Modify your ` _buildScreens` method to create instances of screens with the required parameters
`List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
  return [
    const MainMenuScreen(),
    const LeveloneScreen(),
    const SettingsScreen(),
    PlaySessionScreen(level: yourGameLevel), // Replace yourGameLevel with the actual GameLevel instance
    LevelSelectionScreen(),
  ];
}
`

Comment: and modify your `PlaySessionScreen` constructor to correctly receive the level parameter
`class PlaySessionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final GameLevel level;

  const PlaySessionScreen({Key? key, required this.level}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PlaySessionScreen> createState() => _PlaySessionScreenState();
}
`

Comment: when you navigate to the ` PlaySessionScreen`  make sure you pass the ` GameLevel`  instance as a parameter `currentPageIndex = index;
if (currentPageIndex == 3) {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PlaySessionScreen(level: yourGameLevel)),
  );
}
 `